# Ionic Statusbar White on White

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, statusbar, ionic-native

Has anyone experienced a white statusbar since this new XCode update?

Before the update this code was working...

```
statusBar.styleBlackTranslucent();
```

...now I just get get a white bar with white text. [(see screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFYHG.png)

For relevant debug info:

```
statusBar.hide();
```

is functioning... so I know the cordova-plugin-statusbar is still working on some level.

But when I take out all statusbar code and export from XCode the bar is still white text with a white background.

Of course an update happens on the day I am about to push a Beta.

Here's my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.XX" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>XX</name>
    <description>Create, experience, share.</description>
    <author email="XX@XX.com" href="https://XX.com/">Rob Gungor</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.11.58:8100" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="600" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="950" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="GOOGLE_PLUS_CLIENT_ID" value="XX" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="^4.1.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.4.0" />
    <plugin name="com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions" spec="^0.6.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-fabric-plugin" spec="^1.1.9">
        <variable name="FABRIC_API_KEY" value="XX" />
        <variable name="FABRIC_API_SECRET" value="XX" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-admobpro" spec="^2.29.22" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support" spec="^1.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.0.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="^1.9.1">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="XX" />
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="  &#xA;XX" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="^0.1.24" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="git+https://github.com/mzealey/cordova-plugin-googleplus.git">
        <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="XX" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic" spec="^1.1.8">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="XX" />
        <variable name="CHANNEL_NAME" value="Master" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_METHOD" value="background" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_API" value="https://api.ionicjs.com" />
        <variable name="MAX_STORE" value="2" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-taptic-engine" spec="^2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-wheel-selector-plugin" spec="^1.0.9" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
</widget>
```

[Here's a screenshot of my info panel in XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veaQ3.png)

Thank you sweeties.
xo
rob

Answer (score 4):

Rob's answer is the solution. However, with cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine, my app just didn't work. Removing the plugin brought the app back to normal and the statusbar problem was all gone. So;

I removed statusbar plugin with:

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

I installed the three of these plugins:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-disable-ios11-statusbar
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

And then called

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Thanks Rob!

**Update:**
Found a cleaner solution. You only need

```
cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

In index.html, just add "viewport-fit=cover" to viewport meta in the head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
```

That's all

Answer (score 0):

I installed the three of these plugins:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-disable-ios11-statusbar
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
```

And then called

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

And then it worked for me
(don't ask why)

Answer (score 0):

I did following thing and it resolved all design issues related to 
     ios.

```
1)Install/upgrade WKWebView
  ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview --save

2) Add these line in config.xml
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />

3) Add viewport-fit=cover in index.html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use
`StatusBar.styleDefault();`
It will change your status bar font color to black